# Concatenating integers and strings to a single string

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm trying to concatenate a group of integers and strings into a single long string for use in an svg animation, however my output seems to result in an NaN result when I want something like M15, 140, L20, 34... etc.

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    background-color: green;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

JS:

```
var bubbleObj = function(el, html, cornerRad) {
    this.html = html,
    this.width = el.width(),
    this.height = el.height(),
    this.arrowWidth = el.width()/4,
    this.arrowHeight = el.height()/8,
    this.cornerRad = cornerRad;

    var pathy = "M" + 
        this.cornerRad
        + ", " +
        this.height - this.arrowHeight
        + ", Q" +
        0
        + ", " +
        this.height - this.arrowHeight
        + ", " +
        0
        + ", " +
        this.height - this.arrowHeight - this.cornerRad
        + ", L" +
        0 
        + ", " +
        this.cornerRad
        + ", Q" +
        0
        + ", " +
        0
        + ", " +
        this.cornerRad
        + ", " +
        0
        + ", L" +
        this.cornerRad + (this.width - (this.cornerRad * 2))
        + ", " +
        0
        + ", Q" +
        this.width 
        + ", " + 
        0 
        + ", " +
        this.width
        + ", " +
        this.cornerRad
        + ", L" +
        this.width
        + ", " +
        this.cornerRad + (this.height - this.arrowHeight - (this.cornerRad * 2))
        + ", Q" +
        this.width
        + ", " +
        this.height - this.arrowHeight
        + ", " +
        this.width - this.cornerRad
        + ", " +
        this.height - this.arrowHeight
        + ", L" +
        (this.width/2) + (this.arrowWidth/2)
        + ", " +
        this.height - this.arrowHeight
        + ", L" +
        this.width / 2
        + ", " +
        this.height
        + ", L" +
        (this.width/2) - (this.arrowWidth/2)
        + ", " +
        this.height - this.arrowHeight
        + ", " +            
        ", Z";

        console.log(pathy);
};        

    var bub = new bubbleObj($('#test'), "test_content", 15);
```

JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p9abkmwx/

Comment: You need to give consideration to operator precedence and associativity. There are rules that govern the association of an operator like `+` and `-` to its operands. You're assuming that it will just know that you want to perform math in some places and string concatenation in others, and that it'll just work it out for you. That's not the way it goes. There are rules that are followed, and as it is right now, you're performing mathematical operations on strings that can't be converted to numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets to prioritize all arithmetic operations.

```
var bubbleObj = function(el, html, cornerRad) {
    this.html = html,
    this.width = el.width(),
    this.height = el.height(),
    this.arrowWidth = el.width()/4,
    this.arrowHeight = el.height()/8,
    this.cornerRad = cornerRad;

    var pathy = "M" + 
    this.cornerRad
    + ", " +
    (this.height - this.arrowHeight)
    + ", Q" +
    0
    + ", " +
    (this.height - this.arrowHeight)
    + ", " +
    0
    + ", " +
    (this.height - this.arrowHeight - this.cornerRad)
    + ", L" +
    0 
    + ", " +
    this.cornerRad
    + ", Q" +
    0
    + ", " +
    0
    + ", " +
    this.cornerRad
    + ", " +
    0
    + ", L" +
    (this.cornerRad + (this.width - (this.cornerRad * 2)))
    + ", " +
    0
    + ", Q" +
    this.width 
    + ", " + 
    0 
    + ", " +
    this.width
    + ", " +
    this.cornerRad
    + ", L" +
    this.width
    + ", " +
    (this.cornerRad + (this.height - this.arrowHeight - (this.cornerRad * 2)))
    + ", Q" +
    this.width
    + ", " +
    (this.height - this.arrowHeight)
    + ", " +
    (this.width - this.cornerRad)
    + ", " +
    (this.height - this.arrowHeight)
    + ", L" +
    ((this.width/2) + (this.arrowWidth/2))
    + ", " +
    (this.height - this.arrowHeight)
    + ", L" +
    (this.width / 2)
    + ", " +
    this.height
    + ", L" +
    ((this.width/2) - (this.arrowWidth/2))
    + ", " +
    (this.height - this.arrowHeight)
    + ", " +            
    ", Z";

    console.log(pathy);
};        

var bub = new bubbleObj($('#test'), "test_content", 15);
```